# How to normalize a large numpy array ? - MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape: (40000, 240, 320)
Its an image array and I want to normalize each pixel value as follows:

```
X = X/255
```

When I try to run the above statement, it throws following error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (40000, 240, 320) and data type float64

How to work with large numpy array in such cases ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use augmented assignment with division (`/=`), which will modify `X` in-place:

```
X /= 255
```

Your current code attempts to allocate a temporary object:

```
X = X/255

# Is actually executed like:
tmp = X / 255  # new object!
X = tmp
```

Comment: even though it is in-place operation, doesn't it create 40000*320*240 float64 array ?

Comment: @xanjay, if `X` is already an array of floats and shape `40000*320*240`, no new array will be allocated. If `X` is an array of integers, a new array of floats will be allocated (and the object pointed to by `X` will be replace by that new array) because `/` performs "true division" and always returns floats

Comment: Before it was unit8 dtype, now its float64. i.e. array of size 3GB becomes 24 GB. Is there any way to convert it to float32 dtype inplace ?

Comment: You can make the resulting object be an array of `float32` by dividing by a `float32`: `X / np.float32(255)`, but since the original array is of type `np.uint8`, a new array will be generated (and the one one deallocated). You can also divide by `np.float16(255)` which will further halve the amount of memory needed, but precision will decrease dramatically as well.